# what is visibility check in index scan

Tags: postgresql

I am looking up query optimization in Postgres.

I don't understand this statement:
Index scans involve random disk access and still have to read the underlying data blocks for visibility checks.

what does "visibility check" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL uses a technique called Multi-Version Concurrency Control for managing concurrent access to data.  Data is not visible until the transaction that inserted it commits.  Under other cases, the data is silently ignored for other transactions so they don't see it (except in rare cases, explicit locks, or higher isolations levels).

What this means is that PostgreSQL must check the transaction id's of the actual rows to make sure they are visible for all transactions.  Now, 9.2 (iirc) and higher allow PostgreSQL to skip this check if all tuples in a page are visible.  However otherwise it has to check per row.

Comment: IIRC The visibility map actually shows whether all tuples in a page are visible to *all* transactions. So, basically if a page contains only data that pre-dates all current transactions then there is no need to check its visibility. If you alter one row on that page then the flag is unset for that whole page.

Comment: so, if I understand this. There are some pages that are indexed from before. During subsequent index scan, there is the possibility that some of the rows captures by the pre-existing index has already been modified, but not yet committed and re-indexed. If this is the suspicion, that means all indices are potentially unreliable, and need a visibility check by going to the hard drive. I am pretty sure this is not the case, due to the inefficiency involved. therefore, I am still not sure when does this visibility check occur, and when it  is not needed.